# How does WMI get the ProcessorId?

Tags: wmi, cpu, cpuid

I'd like to get the processor id without using WMI.

But if I try to get it using CPUID with EAX=3, I get an empty result.

How does WMI get the ProcessorId? And is there a way to get it without using WMI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it out by myself, after looking at a cpuid dump.

It looks like WMI is creating the processor id by just combining EDX+EAX from the results of CPUID with EAX=1.

I thought that id from WMI was a unique serial number, but apparently it is not!